# Why does not work redirect 403?

Tags: .htaccess

I have follow problem:
I want to ban some user by ip and use for it .htaccess :

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://somedomen.com/index.php/errorpage
order allow,deny
deny from 1.2.3.4
allow from all
```

it blocks, but not redirect, site based on joomla. Maybe somebody has a suggestion?

Comment: i think its host problem

Comment: post it in Joomla site - http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: so how i can redirect banned user to some page ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your code should be this way round based on your `order Allow,Deny`

```
ErrorDocument 403 http://somedomen.com/index.php/errorpage
order allow,deny
allow from all
deny from 1.2.3.4
deny from 5.6.7.8
```

However the `deny` syntax does not generate an error 403 it just blocks the connection.

You could try this instead. I am not a rewrite expert and this is not tested so have a care.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On

 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^1\.2\.3\.4 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^11\.22\.33\.44 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} ^111\.222\.333\.444 [OR]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^index.php/errorpage  
 RewriteRule .* /index.php/errorpage
</IfModule>
```

Translation:

```
IF their IP address is 1.2.3.4
OR their IP address is 11.22.33.44
OR their IP address is 111.222.343.444
AND the request is not for index.php/errorpage
THEN display the index.php/errorpage page
```

Comment: So how i can redirect banned user to some page ?

Comment: Have a look at the additional suggestion